# Calling a user defined function not working. Instead when its data is used separately, it works. How to fix it?

Tags: python, function

I am working on a project and to shorten the code, I defined a function. But its not working the way it should when I called it. The task I want to do in this project is that, when list of letters have alphabet "a" and "b" in it, the code makes variables "x" and "y" equals to zero. For this I made a dictionary in which alphabets are key and variables are set to zero in values. Now when "for" loop find letters in keys, it will execute the values. This code works fine when I use it simply. But when I copied this whole code in a user defined function and called it, it is not working. Variables remains unaffected. I want to use this code with function.
Below is the code which is not working with function and I want my code looks something like this.

```
x = y = z = 10
letters = ['a', 'b']

def operator(lis):
    dic = {'a': 'x=0', 'b': 'y=0', 'c': 'z=0'}
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if key in lis:
            exec(value)

operator(letters)
print(x)  # Output is 10
print(y)  # Output is 10
```

And here is the code which works without function.

```
x = y = z = 10
letters = ['a', 'b']

dic = {'a': 'x=0', 'b': 'y=0', 'c': 'z=0'}
for key, value in dic.items():
    if key in letters:
        exec(value)
print(x)  # Output is 0
print(y)  # Output is 0
```

I waste lots of time in fixing this. Please fix this problem and must state why it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a problem of scope. I am not very familiar with the use of exec(), but I did a quick search and this solved the issue. Please try it with other examples to check if it works. Simple replace the exec line with this:

```
exec(value, globals())
```

My guess is that the x,y,z used inside the function are considered as local and by adding that argument, you make them global. Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant, absolutely brilliant solution. Thanks wazaki for solving this problem.

Comment: But still I dont know how your solution works. If you can elaborate this it would be a great help.

Comment: From the way I understand it, it's a problem of scope. Basically, the x,y,z defined inside the function are called local variables. They are different from the ones defined outside of the function. This is why when you call the function, the assignment only happens inside the function. By adding the parameter `globals()` in `exec()`. You are  executing the dictionary assignments on a global scope, hence, affecting the x,y,z defined outside of the function.

Comment: @RishabhSemwal From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec): "If only *globals* is provided, [. . .] [it] will be used for both the global and the local variables."

Comment: Thanks guys. Now I understand it.